# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0 (flutter build apk)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, apk

Can anyone please help me with this error ( I even have one of my ListViews shows nothing on mobile ( flutter build apk ) but on web it works fine ( flutter build web & flutter run on web ) ?

it's demanding the version 1.6.0 but I don't know what gradle versions are compatible with that, I tried everything tbh.

These also gave me same thing :

```
kotlin-stdlib
kotlin-stdlib-jdk7
kotlin-stdlib-jdk8
```

The apk that I build works but somehow one of the list views doesn't really work (other listViews, GridViews and the rest of the app works fine ) !

[image]

Flutter version ( + JDK 11 ) :
( Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 patch 2 )

```
Flutter 3.7.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 62bd79521d (3 months ago) • 2023-03-30 10:59:36 -0700
Engine • revision ec975089ac
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

**android/build.gradle :**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    // works : ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }



    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin :
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties :**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
#distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip
```

**android/app/build.gradle :**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    // I added this because of the flutter build apk issue
    //ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"
    //compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        // old 1.8
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.elearning_provider"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        //multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.5.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:$kotlin_version"
    //  old:  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   //  old:  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
  //  old:  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**Terminal (error) :**

```
PS C:\Users\Barack\Desktop\Final-elearny> flutter build apk --split-per-abi

 Building with sound null safety 

Note: C:\Users\Barack\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.8.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java
 uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\Barack\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_windowmanager-0.2.0\android\src\main\java\io\adaptant\labs\flutter_windowmanager\FlutterWindowManagerPlugin.java us
es or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
e: C:/Users/Barack/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0289e7d586838872ea3cc5ef2b0208b5/transformed/jetified-activity-1.7.2/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity_release.kotlin_module: Module wa
s compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Barack/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/bbd170a816c85b7600f21cb0bf06a8e6/transformed/lifecycle-livedata-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-livedata_release.kotlin_module
: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Barack/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/564fb61e5651867636042f1aba0f676b/transformed/lifecycle-viewmodel-2.6.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/lifecycle-viewmodel_release.kotlin_modu
le: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          511.4s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (12.8MB).
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-arm64-v8a-release.apk (13.0MB).
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-x86_64-release.apk (13.2MB).
PS C:\Users\Barack\Desktop\Final-elearny>
```

**pubspec.yaml :**

```
name: elearning
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 12.8.0 #0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.2 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  dob_input_field: ^2.0.0
  file_picker: ^5.2.7
  english_words: ^4.0.0
  emailjs: ^1.1.0
  youtube_player_iframe_plus: ^2.3.2
  video_player: ^2.6.1
  video_player_web: ^2.0.16
  http: ^0.13.6
  dio: ^5.1.1
  photo_view: 0.14.0
  youtube_player_iframe: ^2.3.0
# EditTraining
  dropdown_button2: ^2.1.4
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
# Login new UI
  #rive: ^0.11.3
  flutter_image_compress: ^2.0.3


  #webview_flutter: ^2.0.13
  ######### NEW :
  auto_size_text: 3.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  flutter_animate: ^4.2.0
  flutter_cache_manager: 3.3.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.4.0
  from_css_color: 2.0.0
  #go_router: ^8.1.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  html_editor_enhanced: ^2.5.1
  intl: 0.17.0
  json_path: ^0.5.2
  page_transition: ^2.0.9
  provider: 6.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.2
  sqflite: ^2.2.8+4
  timeago: ^3.3.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.11
  firebase_core: ^2.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.6
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.4
  lottie: ^2.2.0
  google_sign_in: ^6.0.1
  google_sign_in_web: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter_windowmanager: ^0.2.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.7+1
  firebase_storage: ^11.1.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  universal_html: ^2.2.1
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  flutter_html_iframe: ^3.0.0-beta.2
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.0

  # Lessons - HtmlEditor
  #flutter_html: ^2.1.2
  #flutter_html: 3.0.0-alpha.5

  webview_flutter_android: ^3.8.0
  webview_flutter_platform_interface: ^2.3.1
  webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^3.5.0
  sticky_headers: ^0.3.0+2

  #vdocipher_flutter: ^2.2.6


dependency_overrides:
  provider:



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:


  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - lib/images/
    - lib/images/default_profile_image.png
    - lib/images/login-page-lock-lottie-anim.json
    - assets/fonts/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/videos/
    - assets/audios/
    - assets/lottie_animations/
    - assets/pdfs/
```

Answer (score 2):

update kotlin version to the latest
today it's
[image]

Comment: didn't work , got more errors of 1.6.0...

https://i.imgur.com/MtD70Oq.png

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Gradle to 7.4.2 did the trick for me.

Change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
```

Or Open the android code in Android Studio. Android Studio will ask you whether you want to upgrade Gradle. Then proceed with the selected upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the android build.cradle classpath to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2' worked for me.

Comment: didn't change anything else , just that?